# MalformedChunkCodingException processing large CSV

Tags: java

Need some help solving a MalformedChunkCodingException when processing a large gzipped CSV file (10GB+) via HttpResponse.

The exact error message is: Unexpected content at the end of chunk

I have set the CharEncoding of the file to ASCII (but have also tried UTF-8) determined by running the following in a terminal:

```
     file -bi "the file"
```

Now for some code:

```
     public BufferedReader getCSVAsBufferedReader() {

         HttpResponse response = sendHttpRequest();
         GZIPInputStream gzip = new GZIPInputStream(reponse.getEntity().getContent());
         Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzip, CharEncoding.US_ASCII);
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
         return br;
     }

     public void processBufferedReader(BufferedReader br){
          String line;
          while((line = reader.readLine() != null)){
             //Do stuff to process that line
          }

     }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncompress GZIPed HTTP Response in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474193/uncompress-gziped-http-response-in-java)

Comment: The response headers should be informative. particularly Content-Type for the character encoding of the CSV body. You shouldn't be guessing—or at least you shouldn't need to (but then again, you need to know all the other metadata for a CSV document: headers, field separator, column types, quoting scheme with escaping).