# Unzip http response

Tags: java, http, gzip, unzip

Beginner in java, I try to decompress an HTTP response in Gzip format. Roughly, I have a bufferReader which allows me to read lines of http response from a socket. Thanks to that, I parse the http header and if it specifies that the body is in gzip format then I have to decompress it. Here is the code which I use:

```
DataInputStream response = new DataInputStream(clientSideSocket.getInputStream());
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response))

header = parseHTTPHeader(buffer);  // return a map<String,String> with header options

StringBuilder SBresponseBody = new StringBuilder();
String responseBody = new String();
String line;

while((line = buffer.readLine())!= null) // extract the body as if was a string...
    SBresponseBody.append(line);

responseBody = SBresponseBody.toString();

if (header.get("Content-Encoding").contains("gzip"))
    responseBody = unzip(responseBody); // function I try to construct
```

My attempt for the unzip function is as follows:

```
private String unzip(String body) throws IOException {
    String responseBody = "";

    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[5000];
    GZIPInputStream  gzip = new GZIPInputStream (new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes());

    int read = gzip.read(readBuffer,0,readBuffer.length);
    gzip.close();
    
    byte[] result = Arrays.copyOf(readBuffer, read);


    responseBody = new String(result, "UTF-8");

    return responseBody;
}
```

I get an error in the GZIPInputStream: not GZIP format (because gzip header is not found in body).

Here are my thoughts:

• Is body.toByte() wrong since it has been read by a bufferReader as a character string and therefore converting it back to byte[] makes no sense since it has already been interpreted in the wrong way? Or do I reconvert Sting body to byte[] in the wrong way?

• Do I have to build a GZIP header myself using the information provided in the HTTP header and adding it to the String body ?

• Do I need to create another InputStream from my socket.getInputStream() to read the information byte by byte, or is it tricky since there is already a buffer "connected" to this socket?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncompress GZIPed HTTP Response in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474193/uncompress-gziped-http-response-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

> Roughly, I have a bufferReader which allows me to read lines of http response from a socket.

You've handrolled a HTTP client.

This is not a good thing; HTTP is considerably more complicated than you think it is. gzip is just one of about 10,000 things you need to think about. There's HTTP/2.0, Spdy, http3, chunked transfer encoding, TLS, redirects, mime packing, and so much more to think about.

So, if you want to write an actual HTTP client, you need about 100x this code and a ton of domain knowledge, because the actual specs of the HTTP protocol, while handy, don't really tell the story. The de-facto protocol you're implementing is 'whatever servers connected to the internet tend to send' and what they tend to send is tightly wound up with 'whatever commonly used browsers tend to get right', which is almost, but not quite, what that spec document says. This is one of those cases where pragmatics and implementations are the 'real spec', and the actual spec is merely attempting to document reality.

That's a long way around to say: Your mistake is trying to handroll a HTTP client. Don't do that. Use [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) or the [http client](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) introduced in jdk11 in the core libraries.

### But, I know what I want!

Your code is loaded up with bugs, though.

> DataInputStream response = new DataInputStream(clientSideSocket.getInputStream());

DataInputStream is useless here. Remove that wrapper.

> BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response))

Missing semi-colon. Also, this is broken - this will convert the bytes flowing over the wire to characters using 'platform default encoding' which is wrong, you need to look at the Content-Type header.

> responseBody = unzip(responseBody)

You cannot do this. Your major misunderstanding is that you appear to think that there is no difference between a bunch of bytes, and a sequence of characters.

That's wrong. Once you stored bytes into chars, you **cannot unzip it anymore**.

The fix is to check for the gzip header *FIRST*, then wrap your inputstream through GZipStream.